# Are there any solid inorganic compounds that are part of the human body?

Tags: human-biology, bioinorganic-chemistry

I'm more interested in parts physically attached to the body, if that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, your question doesn't seem to make sense as currently written — the title is asking about solids, but your examples are liquids. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: bone and teeth are calcium phosphate.

Comment: @tyersome Sorry, I corrected the error.

Comment: @John Thanks. I'm surprised I did not think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calcium carbonate stones in the utricle and saccule of the vestibular system are pretty interesting (I think they could be what you're looking for).  They are part of the response to acceleration; if they're messed up, you can get vertigo.

Comment: Neat! That works just fine, thanks